# webpack dev-server proxy over https

Tags: proxy, webpack-dev-server

I'm having the hardest time getting my webpack dev server to proxy to my backend.

I'm using Vue and the webpack cli template.

My back end is hosted in a docker container and can be seen at localhost:8443/foo

My devServer config is set up as:

```
dev: {
  proxyTable: {
    '/foo': {
       target: 'https://0.0.0.0:8443',
       secure: false,
       changeOrigin: true,
  },
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 9000,
  https: {
    pfx: /path/to/pfx/file,
    passphrase: 'password',
    ca: /path/to/ca/file,
  }
```

Like I said earlier I can get to my api when I point my browser to https://localhost:8443/foo

When I run my webpack server and try to get to https://localhost:9000/foo I get the error message:

```
Error occurred while trying to proxy request /foo from localhost:9000 to https://0.0.0.0:8334 (EPROTO)
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong and there are no errors in my backend about connecting. I don't think my proxy is even connecting.

The docker command that I'm running on the web server is:

```
docker run -d --env-file=service.env -v /path/to/certs:/docker/path/certs -v /path/for/logs:/docker/path/logs -p 8443:8443
```

The webpack dev server is not running in a docker instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem.

I had to break out the target key and add SSL tags to it.

Instead of passing server creds to the https tag, I did it all in the target tag.